# How to get current location from external button or link click GeoLocation Openlayers3

Tags: geolocation, openlayers, openlayers-3

Getting current location but marker image is not showing (locationStyle)

Currently getting current location on page load or map change.. How to get current location from external button or link click

```
    var locationCircle = new ol.Feature();
    currentLocation = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [locationCircle]
          })
    });
    var locationStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: 'resources/icon.png'
      }))
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
                  target: target,
                  layers: [bingMapsRoad, circleLayer,vector,vehicleVector,currentLocation],
                    // renderer: 'canvas',
                    view: new ol.View({
                     // center: ol.proj.transform([-0.12755, 51.507222], 'EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    //center: [-10807016, 5029327],
                     // projection: 'EPSG:27700',
                        // resolutions: ResolutionsInfo,
                        center: ol.proj.transform([-0.12755, 51.507222], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                        loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
                        loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
                        zoom: 6
                      }),
                    controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }),
                    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true
                  });   

new ol.Geolocation({
        projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        tracking: true,
        trackingOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true
        }
      })
      .on('change', function() {
        var position = this.getPosition();
        var speed = this.getSpeed();
        var altitude = this.getAltitude();
        var heading = this.getHeading();

        map.getView().setCenter(position);

        locationCircle.setGeometry(
          new ol.geom.Circle(position, 20)
        );
      });
```

Comment: `locationCircle.setStyle(locationStyle);`

Comment: Not working.. New - Currently getting current location on page load or map change.. How to get current location from external button or link click

Answer (score 0):

you can use instead of it:

```
geolocation.setProjection(map.getView().getProjection);
```

the function bindTo doesn't appear in the latest API documentation

Comment: Changed the code its working for current location now style is not working the icon is not coming on current location.

Comment: as Jonatas said in his comment above, you can set the style again on your locationCircle

Comment: Try but not style is not working.. New - Currently getting current location on page load or map change.. How to get current location from external button or link click